# How to run code only if button was clicked in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button

I created a new form with buttons labeled as "OK" and "Cancel" 
This form pops up by clicking a button from the first form. I'd like to run some code only if the "OK" button was clicked in the new custom form. This is not a MessageBox().

So far I have something like this:

```
CustomForm c = new CustomForm();
DialogResult r = c.DialogResult;

c.ShowDialog();

if (r == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Run code
}
```

This however isn't working. How do I code this properly? I also set the "OK" button as the AcceptButton in CustomForm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps prefer compacting it like so:

```
CustomForm c = new CustomForm();

if (c.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    // run code
}
```

Also, remember you have to set the DialogResult of the button on the other form to be OK:

[image: DialogResult Property]

`DialogResult` is an `enum`. As such, it is copied by value.. not by reference.

Comment: This works. Thanks! Setting the button DialogResult was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the dialog before you access the result. Right now you are creating the dialog, storing the value in a variable, and then allowing the user to change the result of the dialog. This does **not** change the value stored in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that they are two buttons, then better you can use button click event of OK button to perform your operation.
This may be correct, if I have understand your question..//